# I am stuck in writing the python code while pulling one data from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, apply, vlookup

I have two data frames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','eee','eee','fff'],'module':['ABS','ABS','IPMA','BCCM','HPOC','ABS','ABS','HPOC','ABS','ABS']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff']})
```

So basically in df2, I want to pull values of the 'module' column from df1 with the respective column 'vin' but the challenge is I want all values in one cell separated by a comma.
I tried the below command.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df2, df1[['module','vin']], on ='vin', how ='left')
```

Now the problem with this line of code is, that it is pulling data in multiple rows that I don't want.

My expected output will be like this:-

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'],'module':['ABS,ABS,IPMA','BCCM','HPOC,ABS','ABS']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df2, df1.groupby(['vin'])['module'].apply(list), on ='vin', how ='left')
df_merge['module'] = df_merge['module'].astype('str').str.replace("\[|\]|\'| ","")
df_merge
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='left').groupby('vin').agg({'module': lambda x: ', '.join(x)})
```

It gives you:

| vin | module |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | ABS, ABS, IPMA |
| bbb | BCCM |
| ccc | HPOC, ABS |
| ddd | ABS |
| eee | HPOC, ABS |
| fff | ABS |